# AngularJS soap calls get CORS issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, soap, cors

I am new to AngularJS and SOAP and I am doing a small application that performs a soap call to public APIs. The problem is that I get this error: 
No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" on headeris present.
I've searched a lot, and I have found out that this error is related to CORS. How can I solve it?
I'm using Chrome and I found a plugin that allows it and now I get error 500, so I don't know if I resolved it or if it is something else.
Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chiamata SOAP</title>
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/soapclient.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular.soap.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularSoap'])
        .factory("testService", ['$soap',function($soap) {
        var base_url = "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?wsdl";

            //$soap.setCredentials("admin", "admin");

            return{
                GetCitiesByCountry: function(){
                    return $soap.post(base_url, "GetCitiesByCountry ", {CountryName:"Italy"});
                }
            }
        }])
        .controller('soapCtrl', function($scope, testService){
            $scope.onClickCall = function(){
                    console.log("text before call")
                    testService.GetCitiesByCountry().then(function(response){
                        console.log("Testo dopo la chiamata")
                        console.log(response);
                        $scope.data = response.data;
                    });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="soapCtrl">
    <span>Effettua la chiamata SOAP </span><button ng-click="onClickCall()">Invia</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: CORS issues are usually rectified on the server side - I wont say "fixed", because it may be that the server doesn't want your page to access the resources, so the CORS "block" is not a problem as far as they are cioncerned

Comment: "i found a plugin that allow it" — Those plugins are dirty hacks and generally only work with simple requests (which SOAP is not)

Comment: Ah okay, so what i need to do for resolver this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I've searched a lot, and i find that this error is related to CORS.

Only tangentially. The error is related to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), whereas [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) is a mechanism by which the **server** you're talking to can relax the same origin policy for a given client (e.g., the origin of the page making the ajax request).

If your page's origin isn't allowed to make that request to the server, there's nothing you can do in your client-side code that will make the server allow the request.

If you control the server, look at the CORS spec and the umpteen how-to's for CORS to find out how to implement the reply that allows your page's origin to query it.

If you don't control the server:

- Look at its documentation and/or contact the people who do. Perhaps it has a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) alternative to SOAP (JSONP is another way to work around the SOP, but again requires the server to implement it).
- Set up your own server and make the call from your client to your server and have your server query the other one. The SOP only applies to requests on browsers, not server-to-server.
- The other usual recommendation at this stage would be to look at scraping the information via the [Yahoo! Query Language](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/), but that doesn't apply to a SOAP request.

Comment: JSONP and YQL won't help if the server needs SOAP

Comment: @Quentin: LOL Thanks. By the time I got to that end of the answer, I'd kind of forgotten it was SOAP! :-) Although it's possible that they have a JSONP *alternative* to the SOAP interface.

Comment: I don't have access to the server,  
THe problem is that using SoapUI clinet for making the call, it's works...

Comment: @Wallcraft: No, that's not the problem. The problem is that making an ajax request from a web browser is subject to the SOP. Making requests from other software (such as the SoapUI client, a server, etc.) is not.

Comment: So what can i do for now?

Comment: @Wallcraft: That's covered in the answer above.